# Telerik grid foreign key

Tags: c#, asp.net, kendo-ui, telerik

I have two tables, one is `tblKunde` and the other is `tblHistorie`.
They look like this:

**TblKunde**:

[image]

You can see the `KdNr` is the primary key of it.

**TblHistorie**:

[image]

You can see that `Id` is the primary key and `KdNr` is a foreign key which points to to the `KdNr` of table `tblKunde`.

Now my goal is to display the table `TblHistorie` as a KendoUI grid with columns `Datum`, `Aktion` and instead of a column `KdNr` it should display the Name of `tblKund`.

So basically it is very simple. The grid should not display the KdNr cell instad the Name of the foreignkey table.

This is a snippet of my table which are displaying columns `Datum` and `Aktion`:

```
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
      columns.Bound(c => c.Id).Hidden();
      columns.Bound(c => c.KdNr); // this should be the Name
      columns.Bound(c => c.Datum);
      columns.Bound(c => c.Aktion);
    })
```

This is just a snippet and I marked where the name should be displayed instead of KdNr. Can someone say me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution for displaying values of s foreign table which is hooked up by a foreign key:

**These are the tables to illustrate it better**:

[image]

- `KdNr` is the foreign key in this case
- In our grid we want to display the Name from `tblKunde`
- Our grid is bound to `tblHistorie` so we have to use a foreign key do display the name of `tblKunde`

  1. Firstly you need to query through the foreign table like this. This is done inside the controller:

     ```
     public ActionResult ToDo()
     {
         // Connection to database table
         KundeContext KundenContext = new KundeContext();
         // Select all properties from table. Especially the foreign key!!
         ViewData["Kunde"] = KundenContext.Kundes.Select(e => new { KdNr = e.KdNr, Name = e.Name, Vorname = e.Vorname, Berater = e.Berater }).ToList();
         return View();
     }
     ```

  You have to select all properties you want form the foreign table as well as the foreign key. In my case this is `KdNr`.

Now that you have selected all properties, put it inside your `ViewBag` or `ViewData` so that you can use it later inside the view.

2. Inside the grid:

   ```
   columns.ForeignKey(p => p.KdNr, (System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["Kunde"], "KdNr", "Name").Title("Name");
   ```

   Bind to the foreign key as you would to a normal column (`p => p.KdNr`). It is important that you do this via `columns.ForeignKey`. The next step is to use `IEnumerable` to query through your list and bind it to your ViewData. Behind it put your foreign key in quotes (`KdNr` in my case) and then the column of the foreign table which you want it to bind (`Name` in my case). This has to be in the ViewData from the first step!!